# how to save only date(excluding time) from input in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

Here's my html code:

```
 <label>D.O.B: </label>
 <input type="date" ng-model="dob">
```

In the Browser, datepicker pops up, when I pick a particular date and try to display, both date and time are displayed,something like this "2016-04-02T18:30:00.000Z".
My question is what should I do, so that only Date gets saved(i.e. excluding time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javscript there is no Date-only type. So instances `new Date()` always contain time. You should ignore them in code where you treat it.

When date is displayed in angular app you can use a filter, ex.:

```
<div>value = {{dob | date: "yyyy-MM-dd"}}</div>
```

As an option you can zero time part by `dob = dob.getDate()` before sending it somewhere...

Comment: Then your question should be titled `angular date filter is not working` :) Please share your code. Best is an MCVE in plunker/jsfiddle, For example: http://plnkr.co/edit/JVFAXg8q8qUIhXOvZnUm (works for me)

Comment: A Date-only type is coming: [`Temporal.PlainDate`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/plaindate.html)